# Polymorphic Query Containing All Polymorphic Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphism

I have the following 3 models:

```
class One < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :locations, as: :locatable, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :countries, through: :locations, order: :name
end

class Two < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :locations, as: :locatable, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :countries, through: :locations, order: :name
end

class Three < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :locations, as: :locatable, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :countries, through: :locations, order: :name
end
```

**How can I build an ActiveRecordRelation containing all records of all three models?**

Comment: Could you spell out in pseudocode what you want the query to specify? If you just want all of them, just do an *.all and added the results in a results array.

Comment: @timpone The point of the question is that I want an ActiveRecordRelation, not an Array.

Comment: Have you tried inheritance? Class Two < One   then Class Three <Two

Comment: @SamD trying to avoid STI if possible, but maybe that's the only way.

Comment: pretty sure *.all returns an ActiveRecordRelation in R4. Maybe just merge the results?

Comment: @Pedr an ActiveRecord::Relation represents a query (usually similar to  a select) so I'm not sure if what you want to do can be done (that's why I was asking for pseudocode of potential query). I think what you want is more of a union. I wonder if there's an ActiveRelation version of `included` (ie a callback that you could on that class)? I have had to do something similiar where I would do Location.all and then iterate through each and call locatable; something like:  `Location.all.map { |x| puts x.locatable.class }` . Maybe make that a class method on location returning what you want.

Comment: @timpone I looked at using `UNION`, but one of its requirements is that unified tables have the same number of columns. The reason I need an `ActiveRecordRelation` is I need to pass it into a chain of filters that expect an `ActiveRecordRelation`.

Comment: @Pedr Got it, thorny issue. Could you extend ActiveRecord::Relation and pass that have it's value represent that query you're interested in? Not sure if that's even possible. I would also consider normalizing to another table (which it sounds like you might need to do anyway based upon same number of columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the STI and the Polymorphic association:

```
class Locatable < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations, as: :locatable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :countries, through: :locations, order: :name
end

class One < Locatable
end

class Two < Locatable
end

class Three < Locatable
end
```

And then you can simply do:

```
@locatables = Locatable.scoped # => returns all types of locatable objects
```

---

With a little validates in order to prevent the system from creating Locatable objects but just the inherited models: (kinda makes Locatable as "fake" Abstract class)

```
class Locatable < ActiveRecord::Base
  ALLOWED_TYPES = %w( One Two Three )
  validates :locatable_type, inclusion: { in: self::ALLOWED_TYPES }
```

Answer (score 0):

Models `One`, `Two`, and `Three` are not associated with each other except through polymorphic relationships, so you would need to go to one of those classes to obtain the results you desire.

So, given all records have a `location` and your `locatable` class is called `Location`; you should be able to get all records using something like:

```
Location.all.each do |location|
  location.locatable # <-- this would be an individual record from either One, Two, or Three
end
```

FYI, You can find more regarding polymorphic relationships and how to use them at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: That gives me an Array. As I state in the question, I need an ActiveRecordRelation.

Comment: Since One, Two, and Three are not related otherwise, I don't think what you want to do is possible without a complex SQL join.

Comment: Thanks to @Pedr, I've been writing too many `bash` examples recently.  ;)

Comment: Not a day goes by that I don't add JS curly braces to a Ruby class somewhere when I'm shuffling between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a relation that includes all records of all three models because:

- You can't create a relation directly across different models except through `join` and then you have a hybrid of the records
- Any relation you create through the polymorphic Locatable reference will be limited to those records that are referenced *and* will not actually contain the records, only a reference to them